# Let $ A\subset B$ be a closed and bounded set, and let $\sup(A)=b$. Show that $b \in A$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $ A\subset R$ be a closed and bounded set, and let $\sup(A)=b$. Show that $b \in A$.

I understand the concept but not quite sure where to begin for the proof.

Comment: Closed and bounded set of what? Real numbers?

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there are many ways to do this. I can think of a couple.

***Hints***

- $\sup A$ is a limit point of $A$ and every closed set contains all its limit points.
- If $A$ is closed then $A^c$ is open. Suppose $b \not \in A$ then $ b \in A^c $. And since $A^c$ is open there is a neighbourhood of $b$ entirely contained in it and hence cannot have any elements in $A$ leading to a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

It is always true that there is a sequence of elements of $A$ that converge to $\sup A$ (*). So, $\sup A$ belongs to the closure of $A$. When $A$ is closed, this implies that $\sup A \in A$.

(*) Let $b=\sup A$. Then, for each $n$, there is $a_n \in A$ such that $b-1/n < a_n$. Since we have $a_n \le b$, we conclude that $a_n \to b$.

Comment: This assumes you are working in the reals, of course. It's in fact more general (and then a more general argument is needed).